# Monitor HornetQ

Tags: monitor, hornetq

I'm developing a server which uses *HornetQ* for messaging. I was wondering if there's a utility (whether it a stand alone app or IDE integrated tool) that can I use in to monitor the queue content in development phase (list the queues, its content and concrete messages stored on it)?

Also, what is the best way to inspect the queue's content on production?

Thanks,

Gil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are methods through the JMX methods through the Management interface where you could call for such tasks.

If you are on AS7 the application server control has some of those methods. JMX management is disabled on AS7 for hornetq as the management interface from AS7 is the preferred way of doing things now, however if you miss any of the stuff available from management you can just set the attributed jmx-enabled to true on hornetq and you should be set to go.

There are third party products such as [Hermes JMS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/hermesjms/) as well.

you can also find more information at this chapter: http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.CR2/docs/user-manual/html/management.html